# Contar items en JSON

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Cual seria la manera de contar los items de una respuesta `json` con esta estructura:

```
[['dato', 'dato', 'dato'], ['dato', 'dato', 'dato']]
```

y asi sucesivamente.

Se que usando esta funcion `count = Object.keys(res).length;` se puede contar los items de cada elemento, yo quiero contar todos los items de todos los elementos.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esa estructura es un arreglo de arreglos; una opción sería *aplanar* ese arreglo usando `[].concat.apply([], elArray)` y luego obtener su longitud.

Con aplanar, quiero decir convertir (temporalmente y para el calculo) esta estructura:

```
[['dato', 'dato', 'dato'], ['dato', 'dato', 'dato']]
```

en esta otra:

```
['dato', 'dato', 'dato', 'dato', 'dato', 'dato']
```

Salu2, un ejemplo:

```js
var datos = [['dato', 'dato', 'dato'], ['dato', 'dato', 'dato']]
  
console.log(
    [].concat.apply([], datos).length
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = /* Su JSON sintetizado aquí */
var numberOfElements = data.res.length;

var o = JSON.parse(res);
alert(o.features.length);
```

Comment: @MarcosGallardo quizas sea una respuesta incorrecta, pero no me parece un comentario sino una respuesta valida.

Comment: Sería buena idea (por muy sencillo que sea el código), agregar una pequeña descripción o explicación de lo que hace.